# How Do I Read Rotary Encoder Input on Android TV?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hardware

I'm using an NVIDIA Shield TV to run my Flutter app which will require me to be able to read input from a rotary encoder such as this: https://www.phidgets.com/?tier=3&catid=103&pcid=83&prodid=1010

I'm having a bit of difficulty finding out which way to go with this, however. Would I be able to read the data sent from this with a package such as this? https://pub.dev/packages/usb_serial Does it fall under [UART](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how is the rotary encoder connected  to your Nvidia Shield TV ?

Comment: Oh, it's connected via USB to an encoder interface such as the one in this image: https://www.phidgets.com/productfiles/3530/3530_1/Images/1102x-/20/3530_1_Alt2.jpg The Shield TV Pro has USB but not the regular version. I just wanted to be able to read the input from the interface in my app!

Comment: I think https://pub.dev/packages/usb_serial will do the job if you place **VID:PID** of usb-serial device connected to the rotary encoder in **device_filter.xml** (check the the library doc)

Comment: Awesome thanks a ton!

Comment: Did it work dude?

Comment: Yessir, thank you kindly!